# Who gets the gas for confirming transactions in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am seeing lines in my geth log like this

```
INFO [07-20|10:32:55] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=143  mgas=5.957   elapsed=129.755ms mgasps=45.910  number=4049412 hash=9b6bc7…174802
```

It seems logical to me that I would get at least part of that gas for verifying blocks but I can't find any evidence of this being the case.  What is the mgas and mgasps and does anyone get this gas/transaction_fees for verifying or does it simply evaporate?

Comment: Those are just diagnostic messages print by geth when synchronizing, no gas is involved in verifying transactions, only when mining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to flesh out what Ismael said... (though he should get the credit).

You're importing the chain data to your machine.

The only verification it's doing is to ensure what you're downloading is internally consistent, and nothing has gone missing during the download. i.e. It checks the state data and blocks you download actually fit together nicely. That doesn't mean you're verifying *new* data for everyone else, which is what miners do. The verification is for your own benefit since it ensures that everyone is playing by the rules.

- `mgas` = million gas = the amount of gas expended in those blocks/transactions being downloaded
- `mgasps` = million gas per second = calculated from the time taken to download the data and the amount of gas expended in it (i.e. `mgas`)